# LDAP query: Is int bigger?

Tags: active-directory

This LDAP search filter is invalid: `(msExchResourceCapacity>5)`.

This LDAP search filter is valid: `(msExchResourceCapacity>=5)`.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> >= **Lexicographically** greater than or equal to

This means 5 >= 40, which is not desirable for room capacity, for obvious reasons. How can I check for a bigger number?

Documentation falls short to answer that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no documentation because there is no such feature in LDAP. One has to get all resources from AD and do the comparison in client-side code.